# submitted my php form, but none of the values were sent

Tags: php, forms, email

For some reason, the options are not showing up in my email. I can get the email to send just fine. I can see the body and all its comments, but none of the entries that the user made. I know I am doing something wrong, but I cannot determine what it is.

Also, feel free to mock me if it looks horrible. :)

```
$ToEmail = 'dmandrade1978@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Message from web page!!'; 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$urphone = $_POST['urphone'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$hearaboutus = $_POST['hearaboutus'];

$body = <<<EMAIL
Email: $email <br />
Name: $name <br />
Comment: $comment <br />
Phone: $urphone <br />
Date: $urdate <br />
Comment: $comment <br />
How did you hear?: $hearaboutus <br />
Mail optiom: $mail <br />
EMAIL;

$header = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail("$ToEmail", "$EmailSubject", "$body", "$header");
echo ("Message Sent!");

?>

<td class = "form">
<form action="?" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
<p class = "form">Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
<p class = "form">E-mail:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
<p class = "form">Phone #:<br />
<input type="text" name="urphone" id="urphone" /></p>
<p class = "form">Event type:<br />
<input type="text" name="event" id="event" /></p>
<p class = "form">Date of event:<br />
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" /></p>
<p class = "form" >Prefered method of contact:<br />
<span class = "contact">
<input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone" /> Phone<br />
<input type="radio" name="mail" id="mail" /> E-mail<br />
</span></p>
<p class = "form">How did you hear about us?:<br />
<select name="hearaboutus" id="hearaboutus" />
<option value="internet">Internet</option>
<option value="word of mouth">Friend/Family</option>
<option value="magazine">Magazine</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select></p>
<p class = "form">Message, questions, or availability:<br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="comment" id="comment">
</textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Send email to us" id="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset and start over">
</form>
```

Comment: did you check your outgoing mail log?  That is, I know you checked your email, but on your mail server, did it indicate a mail was sent?  Not sure what system you are using, but most have a mail log.

Comment: Yoour form has the attribute `method = "POST"`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using POST and not GET ? try to `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Please show the sendig form - might be as easy as a POST/GET mixup. In any case you should use `REQUEST['name']` over `POST|GET['name']`

Comment: And you dont need quote variables. `mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $body, $header);`

Comment: <form action="?" method="get" enctype="text/plain"> is what I am using on the form.

Comment: Since you're getting the email, it's definitely a mixup with `POST or GET` or you're using wrong `key-value pair`. Showing your HTML code will solve your problem in under a minute.

Comment: I have updated the original post with my form html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `method="get"`

to

`method="post"`

and remove `enctype` . It's not required in this case.

Also, why is there a `?` in your action? You can keep action blank as it is posting to the same page.

To make things even simpler for you, copy paste the below code and run the file again

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$ToEmail = 'dmandrade1978@gmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Message from web page!!'; 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$urphone = $_POST['urphone'];
$event = $_POST['event'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$hearaboutus = $_POST['hearaboutus'];

$body = <<<EMAIL
Email: $email <br />
Name: $name <br />
Comment: $comment <br />
Phone: $urphone <br />
Date: $urdate <br />
Comment: $comment <br />
How did you hear?: $hearaboutus <br />
Mail optiom: $mail <br />
EMAIL;

$header = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
mail("$ToEmail", "$EmailSubject", "$body", "$header");
echo ("Message Sent!");
}
?>

<td class = "form">
<form action="" method="post">
<p class = "form">Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
<p class = "form">E-mail:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></p>
<p class = "form">Phone #:<br />
<input type="text" name="urphone" id="urphone" /></p>
<p class = "form">Event type:<br />
<input type="text" name="event" id="event" /></p>
<p class = "form">Date of event:<br />
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" /></p>
<p class = "form" >Prefered method of contact:<br />
<span class = "contact">
<input type="radio" name="phone" id="phone" /> Phone<br />
<input type="radio" name="mail" id="mail" /> E-mail<br />
</span></p>
<p class = "form">How did you hear about us?:<br />
<select name="hearaboutus" id="hearaboutus" />
<option value="internet">Internet</option>
<option value="word of mouth">Friend/Family</option>
<option value="magazine">Magazine</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>
</select></p>
<p class = "form">Message, questions, or availability:<br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="comment" id="comment">
</textarea></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email to us" id="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset and start over">
</form>
```

Comment: I was actually watching an online tutorial and it was mentioned that a ? would make the document reference itself (yeah, no idea) - I originally had something else there. But I wonder if me changing that just compounded the problem. Oh, and that only says GET because I changed it to test the get that another user mentioned. and yes, I did change the variables at the top to get also, same thing as post, no luck. I'll remove the enctype

Comment: I updated my post. Notice I added two things - First is `isset($_POST['submit'])` and also added `name="submit"` in the submit button. Now whenever `Send email to us` is clicked, you'll get all the details in it.

Comment: aspirin, I tried the code you submitted above. Same thing. Odd. I dont understand it. the variables seem to match the HTML. I removed all the added junk. yet, still...getting all the html...just not the variable. coming through with name: and then nothing next to name for example. Definitely strange. I cant see anywhere else I made an error.

Comment: The first time around, you email was being sent even if the submit button was not clicked because `mail()` was running on page load. Now after adding `isset($_POST['submit'])` it makes sure that email is sent only after clicking the submit button. It should work now

Comment: aspirin, I hate to be one of those guys, but no dice. that somehow threw my css stlying off. and it never submitted. And believe me, I know what you are saying about the sending the email on page load...somehow I was getting away with it. and it wouldnt send the email until I hit submit. I know, it doesnt make sense. by me adding the info you created about, nothing at all happens. Im continuing to look for that one piece of code that I messed up on haha

Comment: I can't think of anything else that could be wrong. Really weird that your styling got messed up because of `isset` Maybe someone else might be able to see what we both cant

Comment: Ah, I think I have it. I really appreciate the help. What I did was move the isset down below the header....wham, now I get an email and all it's contents. Im not worried about the styling. I am sure I can just redo that. I doubt the php has to do with it. but anyway....perfect. it just didnt work the way you initially had it because the isset was er....too high in the code. either way, thanks!!

Comment: No problem. But it's still a very strange behaviour.

Comment: Yeah I have to agree. Thats the only reason I posted something. I knew I wasn't wrong in theory...but I couldnt determine what the issue was. Ill examine the code...maybe I screwed something up when I cut and pasted. but at least it's progress.